# Is there any relationship between representing beta-equality as its congruence closure, and as sub-expression substitutions?

Tags: agda

#### Representing beta-equality in Agda

I've recently asked [what is the proper way to represent beta-equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54933027/what-is-the-proper-way-to-represent-a-beta-equality-type-for-%CE%BB-terms/54933810#54933810) in a proof language such as Agda. The accepted answer points a standard way to do it is by defining its congruence closure,

```
data _~_ {n} : Tm n → Tm n → Set where
  β      : ∀ {t u} → app (lam t) u ~ sub u t
  app    : ∀ {t t' u u'} → t ~ t' → u ~ u' → app t u ~ app t' u'
  lam    : ∀ {t t'} → t ~ t' → lam t ~ lam t'
  ~refl  : ∀ {t} → t ~ t
  ~sym   : ∀ {t t'} → t ~ t' → t' ~ t
  ~trans : ∀ {t t' t''} → t ~ t' → t' ~ t'' → t ~ t''
```

Which, if I understand correctly, specifies that: 1. the application `(λx.t u)` is equal to `t[u/x]`, 2. the function/argument of an application or the body of a function can be replaced by equal terms; 3. reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity hold. The answer also suggests an alternative: one can define a one-step reduction relation between terms, then define a multi-step reduction relation, and, finally, define that two terms are equal if they can be eventually reduced to an identical term. Both of those alternatives make sense.

#### Another alternative

While I was waiting for the answer, I was looking at this definition:

```
data _~_ : Term → Term → Set where
  refl : (a : Term) → a ~ a
  red₁ : (a b : Term) → (f : Term → Term) → f a ~ b → f (redex a) ~ b
  red₂ : (a b : Term) → (f : Term → Term) → a ~ f b → a ~ f (redex b)
  amp₁ : (a b : Term) → (f : Term → Term) → f (redex a) ~ b → f a ~ b
  amp₂ : (a b : Term) → (f : Term → Term) → a ~ f (redex b) → a ~ f b
```

Where `redex a` applies a single substitution if `a` is a λ application. This says that terms are equivalent if they are identical, or if they can be made identical by reducing/de-reducing any of its sub-expressions. One can prove `sym`, `trans`, `cong`:

```
sym   : (a : Term) -> (b : Term) -> a ~ b -> b ~ a
trans : (a : Term) → (b : Term) → (c : Term) → a ~ b → b ~ c → a ~ c
cong  : (f : Term → Term) → (a : Term) → (b : Term) → a ~ b → f a ~ f b
```

The complete source is available [here](https://gist.github.com/MaiaVictor/df7e7c4d0ce9c44f6475b908ddd9513b). Now, for curiosity sake, I'd like to know if the third solution is also a valid representation? If so, what is its relationship with the previous two? If not, why?

Comment: Equational theories should be represented using equality constructors in cubical Agda. This removes the need to state congruence laws. I think the best way to understand beta eta equality is to follow the categorical idea of Cartesian closure and avoid the sort to of syntactic hackers you seem to suggest.

Comment: @ThorstenAltenkirch what hacks exactly? I have no idea at all how to use cubical Agda, an introductory reference would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A minor problem with this attempt is that this relation is inconsistent:

```
oops : var 0 ~ var 1
oops = red₂
  (var 0)
  (app id id)
  (λ { (lam typ (var 0)) -> var 1; t -> var 0 })
  (refl (var zero))
```

Since we're able to use an arbitrary Agda function on `b`, then, as long as we have an `a` that reduces to `b`, we're able to separate them within Agda and substitute by arbitrary / non-equal values. Thanks [pgiarrusso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53974/blaisorblade) on #agda at Freenode IRC for pointing this.